# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key') react-native

Tags: react-native

i have a project with my university.
We have to create an app who propose foods at users depend on what they have in the fridge.
I start to code the first page of loading on react native and i got a problem that i don't understand.
The application give

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')
    at eval (@react-navigation/stack.js:3:38839)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at eval (@react-navigation/stack.js:3:38802)
    at eval (@react-navigation/stack.js:3:103730)
    at eval (@react-navigation/stack.js:3:116144)
    at ri ([snack internals]
    at Li ([snack internals]
    at Oi ([snack internals]
    at Ii ([snack internals]
    at qs (https://snack-web-player-staging.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v2/43/static/js/2.e69ba1d6.chunk.js:2:4300685)
```

But i don't have any var who's name "key" in my code.

```
    {
      "dependencies": {
        "react-native-paper": "4.9.2",
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
        "expo-constants": "~12.1.3",
        "@expo-google-fonts/ubuntu": "^0.2.0",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "*"
      }
    }
```

```
    import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    import { useFonts, ubuntu} from '@expo-google-fonts/ubuntu';
    import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { View, Text, Image, ScrollView, TextInput, StyleSheet, Animated, Dimensions, Vibration, Alert, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform} from "react-native";
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    import Page_Start from "./pages/Page_Start.js";

    const Page_Start_Navigator = createStackNavigator();
    const ScreenForPage_Start = ({navigation}) => {useEffect(() => {}, []);
        return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Page_Start_Navigator.Navigator>
                <Page_Start_Navigator.Screen
                    name = "Page_Start"
                    component = {ScreenForPage_Start}
                    options = {{
                        headerShown: false
                    }}
                />
            </Page_Start_Navigator.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
        )
    };
     
     export default ScreenForPage_Start
```

```
    import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    import { useFonts, ubuntu} from '@expo-google-fonts/ubuntu';
    import { View, Text, Image, ScrollView, TextInput, StyleSheet, Animated, Dimensions, Vibration, Alert, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform} from "react-native";

    const Page_Start  = ({navigation}) => { useEffect(() => {}, []);
        return (    
            <View style={[{}, noneModeStyles._page0]}>
                <Text style = {noneModeStyles._FoodsRecipes}>
                    FoodsRecipes
                </Text>
                <View style = {noneModeStyles._Top_Design}    >
                    <View style = {noneModeStyles._Bleu_T}    >
                    </View>
                    <View style = {noneModeStyles._Blanc_T}    >
                    </View>
                    <View style = {noneModeStyles._Orange_T}    >
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style = {noneModeStyles._Bot_Design}    >
                    <View style = {noneModeStyles._Bleu_B}    >
                    </View>
                    <View style = {noneModeStyles._Blanc_B}    >
                    </View>
                    <View style = {noneModeStyles._Orange_B}    >
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
    )}
    export default Page_Start

    const noneModeStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    _page0: {
        height: 800,
        width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
        minHeight: Dimensions.get("window").height,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        },
    _FoodsRecipes: {
        width: 360,
        height: 55,
        position: "absolute",
        left: "50%",
        top: "50%",
        transform: [
            {translateX: -180},
            {translateY: -27},
        ],
        color: "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
        fontSize: 54,
        fontWeight: "400",
        lineHeight: 63.2813,
        //fontFamily: "Ubuntu", ??? wtf
        fontStyle: "normal",
        textDecorationLine: "none",
        letterSpacing: 0,
        textAlign: "center",
        },
    _Top_Design: {
        width: 414.365,
        height: 414.365,
        position: "absolute",
        left: -207,
        top: -207,
      transform: [
            { rotateX: "45deg" },
        { rotateZ: "45deg" }
        ],
        },
    _Bleu_T: {
        width: 414.365,
        height: 414.365,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(17, 128, 229)",
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        },
    _Blanc_T: {
        width: 343.654,
        height: 343.654,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        position: "absolute",
        left: 35,
        top: 35,
        },
    _Orange_T: {
        width: 272.943,
        height: 272.943,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 107, 0)",
        position: "absolute",
        left: 70.2893,
        top: 70.2893,
        },
    _Bot_Design: {
        width: 414.365,
        height: 414.365,
        position: "absolute",
        left: 153,
        top: 593,
        transform: [
            { rotateX: "45deg" },
        { rotateZ: "45deg" }
        ],
        },
    _Bleu_B: {
        width: 414.365,
        height: 414.365,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(17, 128, 229)",
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        },
    _Blanc_B: {
        width: 343.654,
        height: 343.654,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        position: "absolute",
        left: 35,
        top: 35,
        },
    _Orange_B: {
        width: 272.943,
        height: 272.943,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 107, 0)",
        position: "absolute",
        left: 70.2893,
        top: 70.2894,
        },
    })

'''

And there is my 3 files, the package.json, the start_page and the app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this in your screen component

```
 component = {ScreenForPage_Start}
```

with

```
 component = {Page_Start}
```

Comment: I try and it's didn't work